# Reference line using first value of series

Tags: tableau-api

I need to create a reference line with the first value of a histogram. The result should be a horizontal line with the first value of all presented. I guess the must be a way to create a filtered value, but all I have managed to get is a single value for the first month, but not that value applied to all series to get the horizontal line. Any help? Thanks.
[enter image description here][1]

Edit: The chart I have so far is this one. X Axis are months from now filtered to 24 months from now. I have a value, the first one in the series (not displayed since it is 28 months from now) that I want to display as a reference line, horizontal, to see which months are above or below that reference line.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jnMt.png
I have tried to get this directly in Tableau with no luck. If it's not possible I'd try to workaround this in the query, by getting that value all along the table but I thought Tableau could do this.

Comment: can you share your workbook or at least a screenshot?

Comment: it would also be good to see what you've tried to do with the data so far

Comment: I added some more info. Thanks for your comments.